# How to create a sustainable white noise generation box?

Tags: environmental-impact, electricity, batteries, health

I would like to create a white noise generation box.  I want it to be as sustainable as possible (within reason), as it will likely be used 24/7.

My thinking so far is to use an old, unused smartphone, and install any one of a number of white noise generation apps.  I'm thinking an old smartphone with a removable battery would be best, and then remove the battery so there is no energy waste from the charging circuits.  *(To prevent the battery from eventually becoming waste, I'll first charge it to 50-60%, and then charge it back up to 50-60% every year or two.)*  Once the battery is removed, I'll plug it into AC power via its "charger", which at that point, I'll just be using as a compact AC/DC inverter.

To reduce energy consumption, I will keep the phone in airplane mode with all radios disabled (cellular/WiFi/bluetooth).  The screen will stay off as well except for a moment here or there if I want to change any settings.

Is that the best solution, or are there better alternatives?  If my idea is a good one, does it need any tweaking to improve it?

Comment: I haven't used them, but you could look for a [battery management app](https://www.androidauthority.com/best-battery-saver-android-apps-266980/) that would maintain the battery at 50%, rather than having to do this manually.

Comment: Without getting into a fun electronics project involving scavenged components and likely a whole bunch of tools you don't have, that seems like the best option. Make sure you have a reaconably recent charger rather than the really old transformed-based "brick" ones (don't be tempted to scrounge one, in other words), because they often used 2-3 watts to heat the transformer and 0.1W to run the phone...

Comment: @LShaver Interesting idea! If the device is not rooted, do you know if any of those apps actually work to stop the device from charging at a certain point?  I use one (AccuBattery), and it alerts me when my battery is charged at x% (you get to define x), but at least without root, it doesn't actually stop the device from charging.  Separately, I *think* that removing the battery will be more energy efficient in the long-haul, but I'm happy to learn something different.

Comment: @Móż Great point about the charger.  I have various chargers of all generations... what's a good way to tell how power efficient each one is?  I do have a digital multimeter and electrical leads.  Actually, let me open a new topic about this because it may help others as well: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-ensure-you-are-using-efficient-chargers-for-cell-phones-laptop-computers

Answer (score 1):

By installing a white noise generating app do you intend to keep the phone connected to the mobile/cellar telephone network & thus continually use phone bandwidth 24/7?

I would have thought a digital recording of white noise played on a continuous loop would be more sustainable.

It is possible to purchase white [noise generating machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise_machine). I see some are advertised online for between $20 and $30.

Getting something that is battery powered, and having two sets of batteries, and the batteries can be charged by a solar panel would increase sustainability.

Comment: Thank you Fred.  I updated my question based on the question you asked in your first sentence.